# What is wrong with my ~./profile?

Tags: command-line, 14.04

I'm pretty new to Linux.  I have been trying to install ant, java, and the android sdk.  In the process have been messing with my ~/.profile and also with my /etc/.profile (dangerous, I know).  Well I did something wrong and restarted my computer and when I would try to login, it would kick me back to the login screen.  I eventually used a tty to rename my ~/.profile and made a new ~/.profile where I just deleted the last part of the profile.  Here is the original file that messed me up which I renamed .profile.copy:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

PATH="$PATH:~/adt/sdk/tools:~/adt/sdk/platform-tools"

ANT_HOME=/home/computeruser/

PATH=${PATH}:${HOME}/bin
PATH=${PATH}:${ANT_HOME}/bin

PATH="$+PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin:~/adt/sdk/:/usr/bin/ant" 
PATH="$+PATH:/usr/bin:/bin:/home/computeruser:/home/computeruser/apache-ant-1.9.4:/home/computeruser/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/computeruser/adt/sdk/tools:/home/computeruser/adt/sdk/platform-tools"
```

In the ~/.profile that actually works now, I just deleted the line

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

and all the lines below it.  Now ant command and sdk command don't work, of course.  If I add the lines back in though, I will break my computer again.

When I was originally changing my ~/.profile, I didn't figure out for a while that you had to restart your computer for the changes to the ~/.profile to take effect (or at least sometimes you have to?).  That is why there is repeating similar lines.  I don't quite even understand what I'm doing when it comes to changing environment variables, and any help understanding what I can and can't add back into my ~/.profile would be ever so much appreciated.

Here's my /etc/.profile in case there's something here broke too:

```
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).

if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ "$BASH" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

# The default umask is now handled by pam_umask.
# See pam_umask(8) and /etc/login.defs.

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

Thanks in advance to any help understanding what's going on in these files and how I can get them working again without breaking my computer!

Comment: Why `$+PATH`?!? Use the existing example: `PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"` to add new directories to PATH.

Comment: You also don't need to add `/usr/bin` and other default `PATH` entries if you follow the syntax @RaduRădeanu posted. Your effective line should be `PATH="$PATH::~/.rvm/bin:~/adt/sdk/tools:~/adt/sdk/platform-tools:~/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this changes:

```
ANT_HOME=/home/computeruser/apache-ant-1.9.4
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
SDK_HOME=$HOME/adt/sdk

PATH=$PATH:$SDK_HOME/tools:$SDK_HOME/platform-tools:$HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

I removed some redundant path and I defined variable to improve readability

When you change your `.profile` you should run:

```
   source ~/.profile
```

or logout from terminal session and login again.